# Error when setting all values in array to zero

Tags: c

I'm just trying to initialize a dynamically created matrix with zero values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void writeMatrix (int **m, int size) {
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<size; j++) {
            printf("%i ", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {

    int i, size;
    scanf("%i", &size);

    int **m;
    m = malloc(size * sizeof(int *));
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        m[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        m[i] = {0};
    }

    writeMatrix(m, size);

    return 0;
}
```

But it crashes with [this error](http://ideone.com/XXXznK):

```
compilation info
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:23:10: error: expected expression before '{' token
   m[i] = {0};
          ^
```

Isn't this the right way of set all matrix values to zero?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use syntax like `m[i] = {0};` unless you're initializing an array at the time it is defined.  What you want to use is `memset`:

```
memset(m[i], 0, size * sizeof(int));
```

Or you can use `calloc`, which allocates memory for an array and zeros it out all at once:

```
m[i] = calloc(size, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: In terms of time, is there a difference between these methods? `calloc` looks faster

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Given that you're allocating and clearing, `calloc` is definitely the preferred method.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is the way to initialize static arrays, not dynamic ones.

In general you can:

1. Pass through each element of the allocated array of `int`s and set it to 0.

   for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
   {
       m [i][j] = 0;
   }
2. Use `memset` to set all the values of the array to 0.

   memset(m[i], 0, size * sizeof(int));
3. Use `calloc` instead of `malloc` which allocates the memory similary to `malloc` and also sets to 0 all the allocated memory.